# Why does pipenv install -e create pyproject.toml file in package directory?

Tags: pipenv, toml

**tl;dr**

Editable pipenv install adds pyproject.toml file to module's source directory.  Necessary?  Why?

**full story**

Using another internal project as a git submodule in our project.  The submodule has code for a Python package that is normally packaged and installed via pip.

Since the source for proper version is already available, we're toying with setting up our project's pipenv to install an editable version from the tree instead.

`pipenv install -e my_project/vendor/other_project/lib/python`

Doing this adds a `vendor/other_project/lib/python/pyproject.toml` file.  Why?  Is there a way to avoid?  If I need to add this to the other project, I can probably make that happen.  But I'd like to understand before I do.

Directory Structure:

```
my_project
  vendor
    other_project
      lib
        python
          setup.py
          module_i_want_to_editable_install
            helper.py
```